# Pivot Table - VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I'd like to create a pivot table which can be automatically updated by choosing the sheet where it will take the information. I have 40 sheets iso-formatted and I tried this :

```
Sub tcd()
Dim CR As String
    CR = InputBox("Num of CR")
    Sheets(CR).Select
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        CR & "!" & Sheets(CR).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1), _
        Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="Feuil1!R2C2", TableName:="Sum", _
        DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
     Sheets("Feuil1").Select
     Cells(2, 2).Select
     Range("C8").Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Sum").PivotFields( _
        "N1")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Sum").AddDataField ActiveSheet. _
        PivotTables("Sum").PivotFields("N2"), _
        "Num of N2", xlCount
    Sheets("SMM").Select
End Sub
```

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work and I can't find out why and thus, how to solve this.

EDIT1 : It gives me the error '5' : **Invalid procedure call or argument.**

EDIT 2 : Concerning the data

[image: Example]

The data contains 6 columns actually but only the first 3 are important.
I can't predict the number of row because it depends on the sheet that will be used.

If you have any idea ?
I thank you in advance for your answers !

Comment: Does it give you an error?

Comment: at what line are you getting this error?

Comment: @Laurent Magon try the piece of code I have in my answer below, let me know if this is what you meant

Comment: I get the error at
`ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        CR & "!" & Sheets(CR).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1), _
        Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="Feuil1!R2C2", TableName:="Sum", _
        DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14`

Answer (score 0):

Reading your post, I assume you enter the Worksheet name in the `InputBox`, therefore **CR** is a String consists of the Worksheet name that holds your Pivot Table's data.

(I removed all the `Select` from the code, they are not needed to create the `PivotTable` you want).

```
Sub tcd()

Dim CR                  As String
Dim PTCache             As PivotCache
Dim PT                  As PivotTable
Dim wsSheet             As Worksheet
Dim PivotShtExists      As Boolean


CR = InputBox("Num of CR") ' assuming you enter the name of your worksheet's data in the input box

' check is "Feuil1" sheet already exists (from previous Macro runs)
For Each wsSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If wsSheet.Name = "Feuil1" Then
        PivotShtExists = True
    End If
Next wsSheet

If Not PivotShtExists Then Sheets.Add.Name = "Feuil1"    

' add a new Pivot Cache
Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(xlDatabase, CR & "!" & Sheets(CR).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1))

' add this line in case the Pivot table doesn't exit >> first time running this Macro
On Error Resume Next
Set PT = Sheets("Feuil1").PivotTables("Sum") ' check if "Sum" Pivot Table already created (in past runs of this Macro)

On Error GoTo 0
If PT Is Nothing Then

    ' create a new Pivot Table in "Feuil1" sheet
    Set PT = Sheets("Feuil1").PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PTCache, TableDestination:="Feuil1!R2C2", TableName:="Sum")

    With PT.PivotFields("N1")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With

    PT.AddDataField PT.PivotFields("N2"), "Num of N2", xlCount

Else
    ' just refresh the Pivot cache with the updated Range
    PT.ChangePivotCache PTCache
    PT.RefreshTable
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this code and get a error 9 : subscript out of range at the line
`Set PT = Sheets("Feuil1").PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PTCache, TableDestination:="Feuil1!R2C2", TableName:="Sum")`

Comment: @LaurentMagon at which line ?

Comment: I got it at line

`Set PT = Sheets("Feuil1").PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PTCache, TableDestination:="Feuil1!R2C2", TableName:="Sum")`

As I said above.

Comment: @LaurentMagon do you already have a PivotTable in this sheet when you are trying to run this code ?

Comment: I didn't have any sheet named Feuil1 si I created one, then this new error occured : **error 1004 : Application-defined or Object-defined error**

On the same line as above

Comment: @LaurentMagon try the new edited code I've updated above

Comment: No error now but it just create a 2x2 table without anything inside.

Comment: @LaurentMagon if you need assistance with what you have in the PivotTable, please edit your post and share how the data for the Pivot Table is structured in sheet name `CR`

Comment: Done !

I just gave an example for confidential issues but the real data is really similar.

Comment: @LaurentMagon running the sample of data you provided I got a PivotTable with all the relevant data inside. What is the value you enter for `CR` ? what is the worksheet name ?